# Why $f(x)=x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} $ Lipschitz but not continuously differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Let $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that $$f(x)=x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} \quad (x\neq 0)$$ and $$f(0)=0.$$  It is clear to me that for $x\neq 0,$ $f$ is differentiable function (as being a product of two differentiable function). So $f'(x)= 2x \sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0.$ Also, it clear to me that $f'$ is continuous at $x\neq 0$.

My Questions:

> (1) Is $f$ differentiable at $x=0$?

> (2) If so, can say that its derivative function $f'$ is continuous  at $0$?

> (3) Can we say that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[-1,1]$?  that is,  there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M |x-y|$ for $x, y \in [-1,1]$.

My thoughts: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \lim_{x\to 0} x \sin \frac{1}{x}$. I do not know how to proceed from here..

Comment: $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right| =|x\sin(1/x)|\le  |x-0|$. That shows that $f$ is diff at $x=0$ and that $f$ is Lipshitz (with constnat 1) whenever $y=0$. Outside $y=0$, $f$ is continuously differentiable, so Lipshitz.

Comment: You have that $x$ converges to $0$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is bounded, so the limit would be ... As for $x\neq 0$, how does the derivative look like there? And what happens, if you let $x\rightarrow 0$ there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Broad hints: Remember that $\sin $ and $\cos $ are bounded. Conclude that $f'(0)=0$. Clearly $f$ is differentiable at all other points. Write down the derivative and conclude that $f'$ is bounded. Use MVT to show that $f$ is Lipschitz. Use that fact that $\cos (\frac 1  x)$ does not have a limit as $ x \to 0$ to conclude that $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @KRM: How should I show that $\cos (1/x)$  does not have limit at 0? Thanks

Comment: Consider the sequences $x_n=\frac 1 {\pi/2+2n\pi}$ and $y_n=\frac 1 {\pi+2n\pi}$. These sequences tend to $0$ but the function has different limits along these sequences. @Learn